# Ironhaul Trail passage with Disfavoured

Tags: tyranny

I didn't go to Lethian's Crossing during the Conquest, and sided with the Disfavoured during the first Act. It would seem, that the only way to go through is by force. Which leads to a massacre quest immediately after arrival at final destination.

Can I still unlock some option of peaceful resolution? Dialogues here hint at internal power struggle (insane leader, kill previous leader to lead etc), we conveniently have the second in command nearby, but no way to act on that that I can see.